# sudoku algorithm explanation formula

Tags: algorithms

I'm implementing a sudoku solver using human way algorithm. Which have 3 constraint, different number ini row, cell and box.

I googled and I got http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/09/sudoku-creatorsolver-with-php/. But I cannot understand how this guy get `floor($cell / 9)` for return_row function or `floor(return_row($cell) / 3) * 3 + floor(return_col($cell) / 3)` for return_block.

I try to figure it out by write down the data in excel and I know there is some pattern like this :

```
[cell] [column]
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      0
```

But how did he figure it out that the formula was `$cell % 9` ?

I want to know, if I don't know the answer for the formula, how can I calculate that ? How can I determine that formula ? What method should I use?

Thanks

--- UPDATE ---

Based on @peterwhy answer now I understand about the row, col and block.
I know about `is_possible_col` and `is_possible_row` , which show that `index = 9*row + col` so from here we get `row = floor(index/9)` and `col = index % 9`.

Now I confused about `is_possible_block` function. @peterwhy said :

> floor($block/3)*27 + 9*floor($x/3) is 9 times the number of rows
>   before the cell, $x%3 + 3*($block%3) is the number of columns before
>   the cell.

Which make me think like this:

```
9row+col
9(floor($block/3)*3 + floor($x/3)) + ($x%3 + 3*($block%3))

row = 3row_block+row_x_block

9(3(floor($block/3) + floor($x/3))) + ($x%3 + 3*($block%3))
floor($block/3) = row_block
    floor($x/3) = row_x_block

col = 3col_block+col_x_block
```

How `col = 3col_block+col_x_block` , because what I know, the formula should be like this : `col = 3row_block+col`.

I know `col_x_block` mean column position on 0-8 block. And `row_block` mean row position on 0-2 block.

Please see [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBJ1TbwlDI9uqHWJFqRlhrm3_9mNYGxwIGA1995ZX-A/edit?usp=sharing) to see the detail calculation.

How do you explain this?

Comment: Hi zae and welcome to scicomp!  I really don't think this is the best site for your question, since it deals with the algorithm to solve a game.  It might do well in the game developers SE or the math SE site.

Comment: @Paul oh, oakay I will ask there. I'm sorry, i'm so confused abaut this question. I already ask in stackoverflow but someone said this is math question.

Comment: If the question is "how do I come up with these formulas", it's just logic/mathematization and I'd ask on math.se. That site is less research-oriented and more suited to explaining basic maths; one can get really insightful answers on these mental processes there.

Comment: The author: It’s an array (line 193) with 81 values representing positions from 0 to 80. The value at `n`-th position is the one you will find on the table at row `floor(n/9)` and column `n%9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`floor($cell/9)` and `$cell % 9` are just how (integer) quotient and remainder are calculated in programming language. The `$cell` indices are arranged row by row. The row number can be obtained as a quotient and the column number can be obtained as a remainder.

Take the cell numbered $42$ as an example. By division,
$$42 = 9\cdot4 + 6$$
hence the cell is located on the 4th row (0-based) and the 6th column (also 0-based).

---

The block number is just sightly more complicated. The first part, `floor(return_row($cell) / 3) * 3`, first calculates the quotient of the row number divided by $3$. So rows $0$ to $2$ are in the first third, and $6$ to $8$ are in the last third. Then this "group of 3 rows" index is multiplied by $3$, because there are 3 blocks for each group of 3 rows.

The second part, `floor(return_col($cell) / 3)`, again find the quotient of the column number divided by $3$.

Taking the same example of cell $42$, which is on row 4 and column 6. The row number
$$4 = 3\cdot\color{red}1 + 1;\;\left\lfloor\frac43\right\rfloor = \color{red}1$$
the quotient $\color{red}1$ means the cell is on the 1st "group of 3 rows" (0-based). And the column number
$$6 = 3\cdot\color{blue}2+0;\;\left\lfloor\frac63\right\rfloor = \color{blue}2$$
the quotient $\color{blue}2$ means the cell is on the 2nd "group of 3 columns" (also 0-based). Combining this two information, the block where cell $42$ is at is assigned a block index
$$\color{red}1\cdot 3 + \color{blue}2 = 5$$

---

Again, take $42$ as an example:

$$\begin{array}{l|l|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\text{Row}&\text{Cells}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
0&0-8&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc\\
1&9-17&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc\\
2&18-26&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc\\
\hline
3&27-35&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc\\
4&36-44&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\color{red}\bigcirc&\cdots\\
\end{array}$$

Notice the red $\color{red}\bigcirc$ is the 43rd $\bigcirc$. Elementary division says $\lfloor42/9\rfloor=4$ gives how many complete groups of $9$ the $42$ black $\bigcirc$s can form:

$$\begin{array}{l|l|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\text{Row}&\text{Cells}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
\color{blue}0&0-8&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc\\
\color{green}1&9-17&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc\\
\color{blue}2&18-26&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc&\color{blue}\bigcirc\\
\hline
\color{green}3&27-35&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc&\color{green}\bigcirc\\
4&36-44&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\color{red}\bigcirc&\cdots\\
\end{array}$$

And the remaining $42\bmod 9=6$ black $\bigcirc$s count how many columns are before the red $\color{red}\bigcirc$. Since the row number and column number are $0$-based, the quotient $4$ and the remainder $6$ also denote the row and column numbers respectively.

Comment: I know how they work. But I don't know to make the formula. For example if I have another table data, for another case, I want to make formula, how can I determine the formula for that pattern. I tried with arhitmatic and geometry but it fails. Also I tried regression, but cam with non integer formula..

Comment: What are some examples of your table data and formula?

Comment: This is for sudoku case : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBJ1TbwlDI9uqHWJFqRlhrm3_9mNYGxwIGA1995ZX-A/edit?usp=sharing . The number marked with red is the pattern. It's like f(x) function. x is the black number, and f(x) is the red one. I just confuse how to derive the formula like f(x) = x mod 9 or something else. Thanks

Comment: Which is what I wrote in my answer, find the quotient and the remainder when the cell number is divided by $9$. Focus on the $9\times 9$ grid in your spreadsheet and the cell $42$. The row number, or how many complete rows are before $42$, is $\lfloor 42/9\rfloor$. The remainder of the division, $42 \bmod 9$, gives how many complete columns are before $42$.

Comment: I know how the function work, I just don't know how to explain that from the table, how can I get the function. I mean, how to get the formula if I dont have the answer (I don't know floor($cell/9) or $cell % 9). I just have the table. How can I explain that from the table I can conclude that the pattern was $cell%9, is that only by guessing or there is a math method ? It also to explain the block formula.

Comment: ok great. So how we get ⌊42/9⌋ and 42 mod 9 to get the column and row is by trial and error. So there is no math method to determine this kind of formula right?

Comment: Why would you think this is trial and error, when this comes from applying division based on a table wrapped by every $9$ elements?

Comment: That's it! I just realize now. Now I understand. I also understand about the block. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: As an analogy, you can try to draw a $10\times 10$ grid and fill in numbers $0$ to $99$ row by row. The row and columns number should be easy to see (the first and the second digit respectively), but in fact they comes from $\left\lfloor \frac{cell}{10}\right\rfloor$ and $cell \bmod 10$.

Comment: hi, can you explain about is_possible_block function ?

Comment: `floor($block/3)*27 + 9*floor($x/3)` is 9 times the number of rows before the cell, `$x%3 + 3*($block%3)` is the number of columns before the cell.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you edit your answer to explain more detail on that? See my edit